# How do I read object properties in EJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, templates, ejs

I have an express server that has an API to fetch food items.
I have an ejs index file that I want to display the names of food.

In server.js I am fetching it like this

```
app.get('/', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        fetch('http://localhost:3000/api/food/all')
        .then((response) => response.text())
        .then((body) => {
            res.render('pages/home', {
                items: body
            })
        }); 
    } catch (err) {
        console.log("ERROR")
    }


})
```

Now this works. Because in the ejs file I can do:
`<%= items %>`

And it displays the array like this:
*{"message":"All food items fetched","items":[{"_id":"658b484b34533ccab5cd809b","name":"Taco","additionals":[{"name":"Sour Cream"},{"name":"Tomato"}],"price":3.5}]} *

When I try to access the first item of the items array in it, it gives me an error.
This is my code
`<%= items.items[0].name %>`

My error is:
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')

What do I do?

I've tried items.items (it renders, but displays blank), I've tried items.items.name, I've tried items.items['name'], I've tried doing it with a for loop and looping thru each.

No luck. Everytime it says it can't read properties of undefined.

Comment: use `response.json()` to parse it as json

Comment: I tried switching the render to in the then() for response, and did what you said. Got an error. Then I did the .json() with the body and got an error too. Idk if thats the solution

Comment: Did you try `response.json()` instead of `response.text()`?

Comment: YES! Thank you. response.json() worked !

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys, the solution was changing (in server.js)

```js
response.text()
```

To:

```js
response.json()
```